# Reactive - Combining Observable Interval with manual triggers

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I have `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` and a subscriber that checks something in DB every time interval occurs. But sometimes when I do that check from DB i want to immediately perform another check(call that subscriber again because I know there is something in the queue).

I have already managed to achieve something similar by combining Interval with `while` inside the subscriber method:

```
 Observable              
.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) //to avoid multiple 'stacked' intervals 
.Subscribe(RepeatAction);


private void RepeatAction(long _)
{
    bool wasSuccess;
    do
    {
        wasSuccess = CheckingInDB(); //Long operation
    } while (wasSuccess );
}
```

But is it possible to achieve that kind of behavior with *pure* reactive?

Comment: What is the `SubscribeInContext` method? Where's that from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

First up though, there is a misunderstanding that you have with Rx.

If you run this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Timestamp()
        .Subscribe(RepeatAction);
}

private void RepeatAction(Timestamped<long> _)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_.Timestamp);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

You'll get this result:

```
2016/05/11 10:37:57 +00:00
2016/05/11 10:38:07 +00:00
2016/05/11 10:38:17 +00:00
2016/05/11 10:38:27 +00:00
```

You'll see that the steps between each value being produced is 10 seconds, not 1. The `Interval` operator simply ensures that the gap between each value is **at least** the duration of the `TimeSpan`, but if the observer takes longer then the duration becomes as long as each of the subscribers take. It doesn't queue up the values.

Another way of looking at it is that the `.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` does nothing as the `.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))` ensures that the minimal gap between values is already 1 second.

Now, to solve the problem using purely Rx operators. Try this:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(_ =>
            Observable
                .While(
                    () => CheckingInDB(),
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default)))
        .Switch();
```

This will try every second to check the database, but once it hits a value it quickly repeats the check until it doesn't. Then it waits 1 second and tries again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sounds logical but I cannot make it work. It never fires CheckingInDb(). Any ideas?

Comment: @Knopo - I just tested my query by copy-and-paste as-is into my dev environment and it worked fine calling `CheckingInDB` as expected. Try just making a very simple `CheckingInDB` and see what happens? Mine was `public bool CheckingInDB() { Console.WriteLine("!"); return true; }`.

Comment: @Knopo - You did subscribe to the observable, right?

Comment: I did not subscribe to observable. Now it works like a charm.  Thank you very much for your comprehensive responses - you helped me a lot.